# Why won't Android Studio debug on my Samsung phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-debug

When I click the debug button, the "Select Deployment Target" shows my phone as a connected device, and I select it. My phone is a Samsung J1 Ace (SM-J110F) with Android 4.4.4, API 19. I have run the app on it several times, even once this morning, and then suddenly, I start seeing the following in the console:

```
$ adb shell am start -D -n "com.bradykelly.heavyweights/com.bradykelly.heavyweights.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connecting to com.bradykelly.heavyweights
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8652', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8652', transport: 'socket'
```

The disconnect is essentially instantly after the connect, and I get nothing on the phone. I tried emulating the phone, but Android Studio hangs on "Waiting for target device to come online". The emulator is started and visible, but just showing "Android" on its screen. And the reason I rather debug on the phone is that it's so much faster than the emulator, when the emulator works.

Comment: 1. execute <adb kill-server> from terminal until it returns " *server not running* "
2. execute <adb start-server>
3. execute <adb devices>

hope it helps

Comment: and try using genymotion, it is still a lot faster than android emulator

Answer (score 0):

Multiple questions inside one.

**Android Emulator**

Android emulator needs a lot ot time for the first start. Be patient!

**Preconditions for installing apps**

Regarding your app/smartphone you have to check multiple things:

1. Minimum API Level inside the manifest <= 19
2. Developer options enabled as well as USB debugging
3. Debug key of your environment is (still) accepted by the device

**Other ideas**

Also an idea, unplug and plug again. Restarting the computer (maybe a solution if you are using Windows). Check the adb drivers.

Also you can give these lines a try (using shell):

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Is you device then listed under devices?

Comment: No, `adb devices` only shows one device, called `420054a8dc49c200        device`. I'll get started on your other advice thanks. I only started working on Android beyond "Hello world" about 3 days ago.

Comment: The fact that your device is listed are good news, then the driver is working. Also I don't see a ´UNKNOWN´ which is great. Good luck!